# How can I avoid zero-byte files on Cloudfront edge locations?

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

We've just discovered that one of Cloudfront's edge locations is returning a zero-byte file for one of our javascript assets. The invalidation is running right now, but I'm beginning to think this phenomenon may be the source of widespread but strangely un-reproducible bugs that our customers have been reporting for months now.

We're using Cloudfront with a Custom Origin (Nginx serving static files from an EC2 server). It would appear that with every deploy to our application that introduces new asset names (e.g. changed file version), we have a non-zero chance of one or more Cloudfront edge locations getting a 0-byte file.

1. Is there any way to avoid this?
2. Is there any way to detect this?
3. `[sentiment redacted]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very similar problem which has been discussed on the [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=101150).  It seems to boil down to your server not sending a Content Length header with your custom origin.

Note the excerpt from the forum, which may be related:

> Unfortunately your origin doesn't appear to provide a Content-Length
>   header. Without a Content-Length header CloudFront can't determine
>   that a truncated object was received and will cache it. If your origin
>   can send a Content-Length header any truncated objects will not be
>   cached. See the [Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomDroppedTCPConnections) for more details.

Try adding the ContentLength header, that should do the trick.